# how to set up a selector from a different UIView object for UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, selector, uitapgesturerecognizer

This should be straight forward but I am having some issues with this.
I have an UIView A which has a function A. I create a Selector for function A in UIView A.

```
SEL littleSelector = @selector(handleTapButton1);
```

I create UIView B and pass this selector to UIView B constructor and save it in UIView B. I set up UITapGestureRecognizer in UIView B and I assign selector from UIViewA "littleSelector" as its action. I get an exception = unrecognized selector sent to instance. I know selectors are not really function pointers but look up numbers. I also made sure that UIView A is retained.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A selector needs to be paired with an appropriate target. If you supply a selector for A and a target instance of B you will have this kind of issue. You need to set the target properly to A so the method represented by the selector is called on the right class instance.

Comment: I was doing that but i was just calling self.superview.And nothing was happening(no crash either). I passed an instance to UIViewA to UIViewB

Comment: I was doing that but i was just calling self.superview.And nothing was happening(no crash either). I passed an instance to UIViewA to UIViewB and instead of calling self.superview I called self.parent(instance of A that I passed)
and it worked. Thank you.